# Generate Swagger from JAX-RS endpoint with external enum definition

Tags: java, rest, enums, jax-rs, swagger

I want to generate a swagger from a JAX-RS endpoint with an external enumeration definition however the generated swagger directly includes the enumeration into the definition of the model. It implies that the enumeration documentation is not generated but also that the same enumeration is duplicated on the client side.

I use the `swagger-jaxrs` dependency to scan my endpoint and generate the swagger json file. This GitHub [repository](https://github.com/nhenneaux/swagger-enum-generation) can be used to reproduce the problem. I also have created a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/2109) on the swagger-core repository.

### The JAX-RS endpoint

```
@Api("hello")
@Path("/helloSwagger")
public class HelloSwagger {

    @ApiOperation(value = "Get all unique customers", notes = "Get all customers matching the given search string.", responseContainer = "Set", response = User.class)
    @GET
    @Path("/getUniqueUsers")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Set<User> getUniqueUsers(
            @ApiParam(value = "The search string is used to find customer by their name. Not case sensitive.") @QueryParam("search") String searchString,
            @ApiParam(value = "Limits the size of the result set", defaultValue = "50") @QueryParam("limit") int limit
    ) {
        return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new User(), new User()));
    }

}
```

### The model with the enumeration

```
public class User {

    private String name = "unknown";
    private SynchronizationStatus ldap1 = SynchronizationStatus.UNKNOWN;
    private SynchronizationStatus ldap2 = SynchronizationStatus.OFFLINE;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "The user name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "The synchronization status with the LDAP1")
    public SynchronizationStatus getLdap1() {
        return ldap1;
    }

    public void setLdap1(SynchronizationStatus ldap1) {
        this.ldap1 = ldap1;
    }

    public SynchronizationStatus getLdap2() {
        return ldap2;
    }

    public void setLdap2(SynchronizationStatus ldap2) {
        this.ldap2 = ldap2;
    }
}
```

```
@ApiModel("The synchronization status with LDAP instance.")
public enum SynchronizationStatus {

    UNKNOWN,
    SYNC,
    OFFLINE,
    CONFLICT
}
```

### An extract of the swagger generated

```
{
  (...)
  },
  "definitions" : {
    "User" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "description" : "The user name"
        },
        "ldap1" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "description" : "The synchronization status with the LDAP1",
          "enum" : [ "UNKNOWN", "SYNC", "OFFLINE", "CONFLICT" ]
        },
        "ldap2" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "enum" : [ "UNKNOWN", "SYNC", "OFFLINE", "CONFLICT" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Expected result

```
{
  (...)
  "definitions" : {
    "SynchronizationStatus" : {
      "description" : "The synchronization status with LDAP instance.",
      "enum" : [ "UNKNOWN", "SYNC", "OFFLINE", "CONFLICT" ],
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "User" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "description" : "The user name"
        },
        "ldap1" : {
          "$ref" : "#/definitions/SynchronizationStatus"
        },
        "ldap2" : {
          "$ref" : "#/definitions/SynchronizationStatus"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it a 'feature' of the `swagger-jaxrs` library ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried the `reference` attribute of the `@ApiModelProperty` annotation?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin It does not work either (see my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42157941/generate-swagger-from-jax-rs-endpoint-with-external-enum-definition/42203462#comment71570075_42203462)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong or is it a 'feature' of the swagger-jaxrs
> library ?

Enum value are treat as primitive value type by swagger and swagger out-of-the-box does not generate model definition for enum type ([see code](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/v1.5.12/modules/swagger-core/src/main/java/io/swagger/jackson/ModelResolver.java) line 209 under). So the is a feature and not related with swagger-jaxrs.

However, you can generate the swagger definition, as per your expectation, by providing the custom model converter(`io.swagger.converter.ModelConverter`).

But it seems to me a nice feature to be available in swagger out-of-the-box.

Following is a ruff implementation which can help you to generate the expected swagger definition.

```
package nhenneaux.test.swagger.ext;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.converter.ModelConverter;
import io.swagger.converter.ModelConverterContext;
import io.swagger.jackson.ModelResolver;
import io.swagger.models.Model;
import io.swagger.models.ModelImpl;
import io.swagger.models.properties.Property;
import io.swagger.models.properties.RefProperty;
import io.swagger.models.properties.StringProperty;
import io.swagger.util.Json;

public class EnumAsModelAwareResolver extends ModelResolver {
    static final EnumAsModelAwareResolver INSTANCE = new EnumAsModelAwareResolver();

    public EnumAsModelAwareResolver() {
        super(Json.mapper());
    }

    @Override
    public Property resolveProperty(Type type, ModelConverterContext context, Annotation[] annotations,
            Iterator<ModelConverter> chain) {
        if (isEnumAnApiModel(type)) {
            String name = findName(type);
            // ask context to resolver enum type (for adding model definition
            // for enum under definitions section
            context.resolve(type);

            return new RefProperty(name);
        }
        return chain.next().resolveProperty(type, context, annotations, chain);
    }

    private String findName(Type type) {
        JavaType javaType = _mapper.constructType(type);
        Class<?> rawClass = javaType.getRawClass();
        ApiModel annotation = rawClass.getAnnotation(ApiModel.class);
        String name = annotation.value();
        if (name == null || name.length() == 0) {
            name = rawClass.getSimpleName();
        }
        return name;
    }

    private boolean isEnumAnApiModel(Type type) {
        JavaType javaType = _mapper.constructType(type);
        return javaType.isEnumType()
                && javaType.getRawClass().isAnnotationPresent(ApiModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Model resolve(Type type, ModelConverterContext context, Iterator<ModelConverter> chain) {
        JavaType javaType = Json.mapper().constructType(type);
        if (javaType.isEnumType()) {
            ModelImpl model = new ModelImpl();
            Class<?> rawClass = javaType.getRawClass();
            ApiModel annotation = rawClass.getAnnotation(ApiModel.class);
            String name = annotation.value();
            if (name == null || name.length() == 0) {
                name = rawClass.getSimpleName();
            }
            model.setName(name);
            model.setDescription(annotation.description());
            model.setType(StringProperty.TYPE);

            List<String> constants = findEnumConstants(rawClass);
            model.setEnum(constants);
            return model;
        }
        return chain.next().resolve(type, context, chain);
    }

    private List<String> findEnumConstants(Class<?> rawClass) {
        StringProperty p = new StringProperty();
        _addEnumProps(rawClass, p);
        return p.getEnum();
    }

}

package nhenneaux.test.swagger.ext;

import io.swagger.converter.ModelConverters;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig;
import nhenneaux.test.swagger.ext.EnumAsModelAwareResolver;

public class EnumModelAwareBeanConfig extends BeanConfig {
    public EnumModelAwareBeanConfig() {
        registerResolver();
    }

    private void registerResolver() {
        ModelConverters modelConverters = ModelConverters.getInstance();
        // remove and add; in case it is called multiple times.
        // should find a better way to register this.
        modelConverters.removeConverter(EnumAsModelAwareResolver.INSTANCE);
        modelConverters.addConverter(EnumAsModelAwareResolver.INSTANCE);
    }

}
```

In your test use:

```
final BeanConfig beanConfig = new nhenneaux.test.endpoint.model.EnumModelAwareBeanConfig();
```

Hops this helps.

Comment: I have pushed a [branch](https://github.com/nhenneaux/swagger-enum-generation/tree/skadya-custom-model-resolver) with the changes you proposed however, The reference between the definition and the enum uses the description of the definition. The test is still failing but I think it is the good track to a solution.

Comment: There was an issue with the description used instead of the reference but I have fixed it in the [branch](https://github.com/nhenneaux/swagger-enum-generation/tree/skadya-custom-model-resolver)  from GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the [`reference`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.0/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html#reference()) attribute of the [`@ApiModelProperty`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.0/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html) annotation:

```java
@ApiModelProperty(reference = "#/definitions/SynchronizationStatus")
public SynchronizationStatus getLdap1() {
    return ldap1;
}
```

Comment: it generates the reference but not the external enum. The generated swagger is thus invalid. I have made a [branch](https://github.com/nhenneaux/swagger-enum-generation/tree/using-ApiModelProperty-reference) on the GitHub repository with your suggestion

Comment: @NicolasHenneaux I see. At least for me, it happens even without the modifications I have suggested.

Comment: What plugin are you using ? You can check the repository what is the difference with your configuration

Comment: @NicolasHenneaux I cloned your repository using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 and just run the `HelloSwaggerTest` test. The `SynchronizationStatus` object is not generated under the `definitions` object.

Comment: Can you share the configuration you used to have it working in your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42157941/generate-swagger-from-jax-rs-endpoint-with-external-enum-definition/42203462?noredirect=1#comment71570793_42203462)?

Comment: @NicolasHenneaux Let me clarify. After my changes, the `$ref` is generated as expected. But there's no `SynchronizationStatus` object under the `definitions` object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135595/discussion-between-nicolas-henneaux-and-cassio-mazzochi-molin).

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [mailing list post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/swagger-swaggersocket/vcT_dr6VdHA/rNiy4WHEEAAJ) from last year I believe it is not trivial and one may have to extend the appropriate Swagger resources. The only other option would be to manually reference the model as per [Cássio Mazzochi Molin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42203462/2553510) (just be careful that renaming SynchronizationStatus doesn't break the API docs due to the forced use of a non-generated string)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this with (using swagger-jaxrs-2.1.3)

```java
System.setProperty(ModelResolver.SET_PROPERTY_OF_ENUMS_AS_REF, "true");
Reader reader = new Reader();
OpenAPI api = reader.read(...);
```